# Debug point inside the java util class

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency

I have set a break point inside the java.util.ReentrantLock code to understand the functionality in eclipse. However i am getting the following error

> "Unable to install breakpoint in java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock" due to missing line number attributes. Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes.

How to proceed on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the build path of the project to use a JDK instead of JRE.

JREs do not include debug information